# How to save a user input as a string in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a basic calculator in java just for practice. I know that in order to save a user input as an integer you have to do:

```
int num1 = number1.nextInt();
```

However whenever I try to do that with a string using this code:

```
char mathT = mathType.nextChar();
```

I get an error. How do you save it as a string? Here is the error:

```
calculator.java:20: cannot find symbol                                   
symbol  : method nextChar()                                              
location: class java.util.Scanner                                        
char mathT = mathType.nextChar();                                    
                     ^                                               
1 error
```

Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class calculator
{

 static Scanner mathType = new Scanner(System.in);

 static Scanner number1 = new Scanner(System.in);

 static Scanner number2 = new Scanner(System.in);


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {


System.out.println("Enter M, D, S, or A");
int num2 = number2.nextInt();
char mathT = mathType.nextChar();
int num1 = number1.nextInt();




if (mathT == 'M')
{
  System.out.println(num1 * num2);
}
else if (mathT == 'D')
{
  System.out.println(num1 / num2);
}
else if (mathT == 'A')
{
  System.out.println(num1 + num2);
}
else if (mathT == 'S')
{
  System.out.println(num1 - num2);
}
else
{
  System.out.println("You did not enter a valid operation.");
}


}


}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what the error is?

Comment: @Thiru Here is the full error message: calculator.java:20: cannot find symbol                                   
symbol  : method nextChar()                                              
location: class java.util.Scanner                                        
    char mathT = mathType.nextChar();                                    
                         ^                                               
1 error

Comment: You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist. Read the javadoc of the class you're using, instead of randomly trying things. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html. And you don't need 3 different scanners to read from System.in. One is sufficient.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not in a class. I'm learning on my own.

Comment: Scanner is a class. You're using it. So you should read its javadoc.

Comment: To clarify, @JBNizet means a class by the Java definition, not a class as in a series of lessons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class does not have a `nextChar()` method. Instead you can do:

```
char mathT = mathType.next().charAt(0);
```

Which will take the first char of the next complete token and assign it to `mathT`.

---

Additionally don't have more than one `Scanner` object to read from `System.in`